# Python: For Loop return total price if in stock?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, dictionary, return

I'm quite new to python and this is one of the tasks from codeacademy that I am stuck on. The compute_bill function has to loop through each item in "food (list)" and only add the price of the item to "total (variable)" if the item's stock count is greater than zero. Next, if the item is in stock and after it has added the price to the total, subtract one from the item's stock count.

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!

def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for price in food:
        if stock[price] > 0:
            total += prices[price]
    return total
```

It returns an error saying that *

> calling compute_bill with a list containing 1 apples, 3 pears, 1
>   oranges and 9 bananas resulted in 46.5 instead of the correct 34.5

*. But clearly, it says in the stock dictionary that there are 0 apples, 15 pears, 32 oranges and 6 bananas. Or am I supposed to make a list/dictionary to put in the "food" argument in the compute_bill function?

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think i may have answered your question , please check and tell me if this is good for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not decrementing stock's count which leads to 3 more bananas(3*4=12) added to total price. You can use [dictionary.update()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm) method for decrementation.

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        if stock[item] > 0:
            total += prices[item]
            stock.update({item: stock[item]-1})

    return total
```

Comment: Nice!, the answer was straight forward and I managed to solve it after reading this. Thanks Lafexios

Answer (score 0):

i think i have a solution, you need to know the number of each item in the list and if it is more that the stock count you need to lower your order to match the number of this item in the stock... never mind , here is a code that you can start with and improve in time :

```
shopping_list = ["apple","pear","pear","pear","orange","banana","banana",
             "banana","banana","banana","banana","banana","banana","banana"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
 }



def compute_bill(food):
    banana_number = food.count("banana")
    apple_number = food.count("apple")
    orange_number = food.count("orange")
    pear_number = food.count("pear")
    total = 0
    hash_table = {"apple":apple_number,"banana":banana_number,
                  "orange":orange_number,"pear":pear_number}
    for key in hash_table:
        if hash_table[key]>stock[key]:
            hash_table[key] = stock[key]
        else:
            hash_table[key] = hash_table[key]

        total += prices[key]*hash_table[key]
        stock[key] -= hash_table[key]

    print total
    print stock

if __name__ == '__main__':
    compute_bill(shopping_list)
```

i hope i have helped @Adrian

Comment: The output is correct but your method is not what is asked in the question. You are just exchanging values in shopping list and stock. `if the item is in stock and after it has added the price to the total, subtract one from the item's stock count.`

Comment: Yes, exactly and you don't need those counts if you update dictionary iteratively.

Comment: @Lafexlos i have edited.. please check if this what it asked for... +1 for you, you were right

Answer (score 0):

You can also decrement by just saying

```
stock[price]-=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zozo = ["apple","pear","banana"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    banana_number = food.count("banana")
    apple_number = food.count("apple")
    orange_number = food.count("orange")
    pear_number = food.count("pear")
    total = 0
    hash_table = {"apple":apple_number,"banana":banana_number,
                  "orange":orange_number,"pear":pear_number}
    for key in hash_table:
        if hash_table[key]>stock[key]:
            hash_table[key] = stock[key]
        else:
            hash_table[key] = hash_table[key]

        total += prices[key]*hash_table[key]
        stock[key] -= hash_table[key]

    return total
    return stock

if __name__ == '__main__':
    compute_bill(shopping_list)
```

Comment: Instead of simply posting code, I think it would be cool if you could explain where the problem/error was :)

Answer (score 0):

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}
```

Code below:

```
def compute_bill(food):
   total = 0
   for item in food:
      if stock[item] > 0:
         total += prices[item]
         prices.update({item: prices[item]})
   return total
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0

    for item in food:
        if stock[item] > 0:
            total += prices[item]
            stock[item]-=1
    return total
```